# Schrodinger equation with imaginary potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, potential, complex-numbers

Is the following problem studied in literature:

Find the spectrum of operator: $-\Delta +ix $ on the real line?

I believe one has to work on $L^2[\mathbb{R},e^{-x^2}dx]$.

Comment: The Hamiltonian $H=-\Delta +ix$ is possibly studied in the [PT-symmetric](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=pt+symmetric) literature.

Comment: Well, if you use $e^{-x^2}$ weight wouldn't both of the resulting Airy functions for *any complex energy* normalizable?

Comment: @OON, what would that mean for the spectrum ?